# Why use jQuery(selector).get(0) instead of jQuery(selector)[0] to get DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery is there any benefit to using `$(selector).get(0)` over `$(selector)[0]` if I just want to get the first item in the jQuery array as a DOM element?

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm"></form>
```

Javascript:

```
var selector = '#myForm';
var domElement = $(selector).get(0); //Returns [object HTMLFormElement]

//Or
var domElement = $(selector)[0]; //Also returns [object HTMLFormElement]
```

- `.get()` is more characters to type.
- Both methods return the same result if the `$(selector)` is empty (`undefined`)
- [The jQuery documentation on `.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) notes that you can simply use the index accessor to get the nth element, but you don't get the other benefits of `.get()` such as using a negative number to return items from the end of the array.
- Also, you can call `.get()` with no arguments to return all the DOM elements of the jQuery array.

Comment: I think you answered your question

Comment: Stylistically I prefer `.get(0)` because `[0]` is too obscure for such a momentous conversion.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`.get` allows you to use negative indices. For example:

```
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
<span>3</span>
```

`$("span").get(-1);` refers to the third `span`.

But if you don't need that feature and only want to select one element `.get(0)` and `[0]` are the same. Notice the `this[num]`:

```
// jQuery code
get: function (num) {
    return num == null ?

    // Return a 'clean' array
    this.toArray() :

    // Return just the object
    (num < 0 ? this[this.length + num] : this[num]);
},
```

Comment: Matt - your answer is still valuable because you pointed out the jQuery source code. I should have thought of just looking at it!

Comment: Agreed that code is helpful. But a multi-line ternary operator reminds me of [this](https://imgur.com/6lBGu) or [this](https://imgur.com/gallery/am1tAPZ).

Answer (score 7):

I have too low a rep to comment on ericbowden's answer, but here is a jsperf test comparing the two operations:

http://jsperf.com/selector-get-0-vs-selector-0

Consensus (on Chrome 32): Basically the same, very minor advantage towards `[0]`

Answer (score 6):

In the interest of speed I created a jsfiddle that loops over each 10,000,000 times. I created two tests with a form at the beginning of the document and the end with 1200 lines of dummy HTML between. Here are some preliminary results:

```
Test1
form at beginning with .get(0): 15981ms - faster
form at beginning with [0]:     16089ms
form at end with .get(0):       16554ms
form at end with [0]:           15969ms - faster

Test2
form at beginning with .get(0): 14137ms
form at beginning with [0]:     14034ms - faster
form at end with .get(0):       13756ms - faster
form at end with [0]:           14492ms

Test3
form at beginning with .get(0): 15952ms - faster
form at beginning with [0]:     16810ms
form at end with .get(0):       15905ms
form at end with [0]:           15532ms - faster
```

It looks like no significant difference in speed can be seen. However you would have to check in different browsers to be sure.

You can check out the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/AFfYx/ (takes about a minute to run)

Answer (score 0):

As an ardent fan of code **readability** by humans I suggest neither approach is satisfying. `.get(0)` and `[0]` look too much like container indexing. More is at stake when converting a jQuery object to a DOM object. So I introduce a function to [name](https://wiki.c2.com/?IntroduceExplainingVariable) what's going on.

```
function dom_from_$($jquery_object) {
    var dom_object = $jquery_object.get(0);
    return dom_object;
}
```

Used like this:

```
var dom = dom_from_$($(selector));
```

Notice how the dollar signs are close to each other? I also have a policy of naming conversion functions in the form `x_from_y`, as in `x = x_from_y(y);`  Notice how the x's and y's are close to each other.