# How is an event added to multiple elements with jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have the following markup:

```
<ul>
    <li class="one"></li>
    <li class="one"></li>
    <li class="one"></li>
</ul>
```

I add the folowing jquery to perfprm onclick function:

```
$(".one").click(function(){
        var text = this.innerHTML;
        alert(text);

    })
```

The click function is assigned to all the three `li` elements. Usualy in javascript `document.getElementsByClassName("one").myprop` would return the first element with class name `one`'s property `myprop`. Similarly if I add an event listener to `document.getElementsByClassName("one")` the event will be attached to the first element with class name `one`. E.g.

```
var one = document.getElementsByClassName("one");  
one.addEventListener("click", function(){
  alert();
});
```

will cause alert poup to appear when first `li` element is clicked.

Similarly jquery should assign the function to only the first element with class name `one`.

So how does jquery assign a function to all the elements with class name `one`?

Comment: nop , `document.getElementsByClassName("one")`  return html element collection

Comment: Who said the `document.getElementsByClassName("one")` will return first element?

Answer (score 2):

> So how does jquery assign a function to all the elements with class
>   name one?

The original selector is a collection of all `".one"` elements passed to [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

> In the first formulation listed above,  `jQuery()` — which can also be
>   written as `$()` — searches through the `DOM` for **any** elements
>   that match the provided selector and creates a new jQuery object that
>   references these elements:
>
> ```
> $( "div.foo" );
> ```

emphasis added at "**any**".

`.one()` calls `.on()`

```
function one(types, selector, data, fn) {
    return this.on(types, selector, data, fn, 1);
}
```

which calls `.each()` to attach event to each element at original selector `$(".one")`

```
return this.each(function () {
    jQuery.event.add(this, types, fn, data, selector);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName),

> Javascript 'getElementsByClassName' returns an array-like object of
>   all child elements which have all of the given class names.

So, you will not actually get only one result. Almost the same in your sample, `$('.one')` simply does the same.

And to get the first element of the returned elements, you can use;

```
var $jQueryObject = $('.one').eq(0);
//
var domElem = $('.one').get(0);
```

So, if you just want to assign the event handler to the first one, you can do;

```
$(".one").eq(0).click(function(){
    var text = this.innerHTML;
    alert(text);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you may use `:nth-child(0)` or `:eq(1)` to point to first of class. Internally it gets all the elements as an list and then when you give `(0)` it means `index=0`. In case of `:nth-child()` index starts from 0 whereas in `:eq()` index starts with 1.

The JavaScript `getElementsByClassName` does the same thing.

Example :

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  //alert($(".one:nth-child(1)").text());
  alert($(".one:eq(0)").text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="one">A</li>
  <li class="one">B</li>
  <li class="one">C</li>
</ul>

<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: Read the question properly. It's not asking how to do x using jQuery, but how jquery does X (internally). OP has wrong information about the native implementation. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @TJ  jQuery/JS internally gets a list of elements & then we may access it with its index. Answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

> The getElementsByClassName() method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified class name, as a NodeList object.
>
> The NodeList object represents a collection of nodes. The nodes can be accessed by index numbers. The index starts at 0.te

`get(0)` will solve your problem.

> The get() method gets the DOM elements specified by the selector.

For more info you can refer [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504662/why-use-jqueryselector-get0-instead-of-jqueryselector0-to-get-dom-elemen).

Also see [doc](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

```
$('.one').get(0).click(function()
{
    var text = this.innerHTML;
    alert(text);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement "**jquery should assign the function to only the first element with class name one**" here is the code that can be of some help.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("li.one:first-child").on("click",function(){
        /*Your actions go here*/
        var text =$(this).html();
         alert(text);
        });
    });
```